# What payment gateways work well on appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, model

Well, I've been building some free apps on top of appengine, but now I want to start charging money.  My question is:

What is the best way to collect payments from users.  Do certain services (paypal, google checkout, etc) work better/worse with AppEngine's library restrictions?   Are there any good examples or tutorials to help me learn how to do this?

Comment: This is not off topic, though the question should probably be reworded to be more clear.  The question is not "how do i monetize my site?".  It is "What payment services work well on the app engine infrastructure.  This is a valid question to ask about app engine, which restricts what libraries are available to be used.  Nick's answer that google checkout and paypal both work on appengine is useful information.

Comment: I have edited the question to focus it more on the technical aspects of collecting payment rather than the more ephemeral "paid models"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also just something to point out about the implementation, a simple boolean property on your user object should allow you to easily turn functions in your app on and off, depending on which tier your user has paid for.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this any way you want, really - and there's nothing App Engine specific about it. For example, you could use Google Checkout or Paypal, and charge users on any basis you want.

Comment: So there are no advantages to using Google Checkout?  I would have thought there would be some synergy with the User API.

Comment: @Peter: "..synergy with.." that's a funny one.  Google is very large company with a lot of different dev efforts going on.  As with any company with such a diverse product offering, you're sometimes more likely to find a third party with tighter integration with their api.

Comment: @Chris And of course as soon as they do integrate, we will yell at them for favoring their own products.  :)  Personally I want them to synergize App Engine with AdWords - have X% ad revenue directed straight into quota payments.

Comment: @Peter: ;) absolutely we have to have something to gripe about.

Comment: No, there's no special integration between App Engine and Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://Spreedly.com or http://Recurly.com. Both are billing solution SaaS apps. http based api's and easy to use. I use Spreedly.com

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to sell business apps you could integrate with the [Google Apps Marketplace](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/) which [uses Google Checkout](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/billing.html) for billing.